# Nested sequence containing sequences

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3seq

I am trying to create a nested sequence where each element is a sequence but for some reason it does not compile and exists with an emergency stop.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {Ne}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {NV}

\seq_new:N \l__outer_seq
\seq_new:N \l__inner_seq
\NewDocumentCommand\add{m m m}
{
    \seq_clear:N \l__inner_seq
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__inner_seq {##1}
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__inner_seq {##2}
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__inner_seq {##3}
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__outer_seq \l__inner_seq
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{MWE}
\add{1}{2}{3}
\end{document}
```

After the call of `add{1}{2}{3}` the outer sequence contains one element which is a (inner) sequence containing the element 1,2 and 3

Visual:
[[1, 2, 3]] - the brackets represent a sequence

Comment: So you want to append to `\l__inner_seq` the items in `\l__outer_seq`? Please try and explain what `\l__inner_seq` is expected to contain at the end of the process.

Comment: @egreg I specified the MWE with more information. I hope this is helpfull,.

Comment: `:NV` means it takes two arguments so `\seq_put_right:NV \l__outer_seq`  is missing something.

Comment: Sorry, but sequences cannot contain other sequences. They're not something like Perl or Python arrays. Maybe you could explain what's the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @egreg but they could contain a variable that holds a sequence which is perhaps all the OP needs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's not the same, I believe.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't see that the second argument is missing..., thanks.

Comment: @egreg It is not possible to have a nested list/sequence?

Comment: @egreg it's not the same, which is why it works:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer sequence can hold a variable holding an inner sequence, so:

```
The sequence \l__outer_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\l__inner_seq }.
<recently read> }
                 
l.26 \seq_show:N\l__outer_seq
                             
? 
The sequence \l__inner_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1}
>  {2}
>  {3}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.28 \seq_map_function:NN \l__outer_seq\seq_show:N
                                                  
?
```

This shows the outer sequence then maps over that showing the inner sequence is 1,2,3

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {Ne}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {NV}

\seq_new:N \l__outer_seq
\seq_new:N \l__inner_seq
\NewDocumentCommand\add{m m m}
{
    \seq_clear:N \l__inner_seq
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__inner_seq {#1}
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__inner_seq {#2}
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__inner_seq {#3}
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__outer_seq \l__inner_seq
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{MWE}
\add{1}{2}{3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_show:N\l__outer_seq

\seq_map_function:NN \l__outer_seq\seq_show:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your post almost solved all my questions. The command call e.g. `\add{7}{8}{\textbf{9}}` seems not to work if an argument contains a macro. Do you perhaps know a solution to that?

Comment: @Nyanyan I copied you and used `:Ne`  so they are expanded perhaps you want `:Nn` so you just add the tokens as supplied

Comment: `:Nn` does not work. Tried to test it all day but no success :(

Comment: `:Nn` will add the argument  not its expansion, If something doesnt work make an example and ask a new question

Comment: You're storing a pointer to the current value of `\l__inner_seq`, not the value… See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618725/4427

Comment: @egreg yes of course that's what I meant by the first sentence. Or did you mean to point that out to the OP (who probably needs to generate a unique name each time for the inner seq)